# Wicket page expires on backbutton

Tags: ajax, wicket, wicket-1.5

In my wicket application, I am encountering a strange problem. When a user presses the back button of the browser the page expires, and shows PageExpiredErrorPage.

I have been reading about it since morning and have already added the `no cache` header to my page like :

```
@Override
protected void configureResponse(WebResponse response) {
    super.configureResponse(response);
    response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache, max-age=0, no-store");
}
```

The page in question has a Modal Window and other Ajax components too.
Another thing that I noticed that when the page has a bookmark-able URL the back button works fine but when it has non-bookmarkable url the page expires. For example if url is like

```
`http://localhost:8081/myapp/app/wicket/bookmarkable/com.myapp.foo.bar.FooPage?2`
```

back button works, but if my url is like

```
`http://localhost:8081/myapp/app/wicket/page?3`
```

I get a PageExpired window.

Answer (score 0):

PageExpiredException is thrown when a Page instance cannot be found by its id in the page stores. The page may be missing because of reasons like:

- the page have never been stored there, e.g. an error occurred during
  the storing process (check your logs for serialization errors)
- the http session has expired and thus all pages    related to this
  session are erased too
- the page instance has been erased because the store size exceeded